# Lower bound on the mean for an exponential distribution at a confidence level of 95%

Tags: self-study, confidence-interval, exponential-distribution, bounds

for the life of me I simply cannot wrap my head around confidence intervals and upper/lower bounds on parameters.

E.g

$$ f(t;\tau) = \frac{1}{\tau} e^{-t/\tau}, \qquad t \geq0
$$

If $t=1$ (a single value) how can I find the lower limit on $\tau$ at a confidence level of 95%?

I imagine I'll have to integrate the pdf and set it equal to either 0.95 or 0.05 (I think), but I do not know where to go with this.

Thanks in advance for any insight you can offer me.  I know this is quite simple but I struggle with this greatly for whatever reason.

Comment: What's the distribution of $t/\tau$?

Comment: Sorry, typo.  Distribution of t, with $\tau$ the mean.

Comment: No, I'm giving you a clue how to do the question. Please add the `self-study` tag and read its [tag-wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info), modifying your question to meet the guidelines there.

Comment: No idea what that "clue" is but thanks for your tip with regards to self-study tag.

Comment: What is the numerical value of the natural logarithm of $0.95$?

Comment: If you can answer my question, I would ask another. A series of such leading questions will allow you to do the problem yourself, at which point the reason for the questions would become clear. The need for this is explained in the `self-study` [tag wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Alternatively, you could ask a much more specific question which could perhaps be answered more directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to approach such problems is to find a [pivotal quantity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pivotal_quantity), $Q$, which is a function of data and an unobservable quantity (such as a parameter, $\tau$, say) whose distribution doesn't depend on that unobservable quantity.

You can then specify the endpoints $l_Q,u_Q$ of an interval for $Q$ that includes a specified fraction ($1-\alpha$) of its distribution (e.g. by placing bounds at the $\alpha/2$ and $1-\alpha/2$ quantiles of $Q$); this interval will be the same whatever the value of the unknown quantity (/parameter).

[image]

(that is not the density of a suitable Q for this problem)

From those limits for $Q(\mathbf{x;\tau})$, you can then back out limits  of an interval for $\tau$ itself $l_\tau,u_\tau$ which will have the given ($1-\alpha$) coverage (i.e. would encompass the parameter with the given frequency across many such trials).

To that end, consider the distribution of $t/\tau$.